# I keep getting a 401 error when trying to login to my app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a user/login route set up that fetches a user, compares the users password with a hashed password, generates a token, and then sends the token to the front end, but for some reason I keep getting a 401 error in the console on the front end and it ends up in my last catch block.

I've tried console logging things out, it gets to "hello" but doesn't get into the first .then() which is confusing. Also it seems to sometimes work locally but on my heroku server it never works.

```
app.post("/user/login", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('hello')
  let fetchedUser;
  User.find({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed1"
        });
      }
      fetchedUser = user[0];
      console.log('req.body.password', req.body.password)
      console.log('user password', user.password)
      return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password);
    }).then(result => {
      if (!result) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed2"
        });
      }
      const token = jwt.sign(
        { email: fetchedUser.email, userId: fetchedUser._id },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: "1h" }
      );
      console.log(token);
      res.status(200).json({
        token: token,
        expiresIn: 3600
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "AUTH FAILED 3"
      });
    });
});
```

I expect the user to be logged in after using this path, but instead it's throwing an error in the last catch block. It won't even get into the console.log('hello') on my heroku server.

Comment: Which 401 is it hitting?  You have three of them.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's hitting the AUTH FAILED 3 so the last one.

Comment: I'd suggest you `console.log(err)` in the `.catch()` so you can see exactly what error got it there.

Comment: This is not what is causing your problem, but when you do `return res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth failed1"});` inside a `.then()`, that's going to send the interpreter onto the next `.then()` handler which is not what you want.  You can simplify your code by doing `throw someError` and sending all the 401 responses from your `.catch()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah i tried that, and for some reason it doesn't want to log out in prod, and I can't always get it to error in dev.....

Comment: Then, put a bunch more info about the error in the actual response you send back to the client and log it in the client.  You need to see what error is happening somehow.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok I'll do that and report back.

Comment: @jfriend00 well, I'm a dumbass. It was the JWT secret, I forgot to put it into my env vars on the Heroku server. I will now hide in shame. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I posted an answer in order to wrap up the question.  You really always want to log errors like this on the server because a simple typo in your code can also cause something like this where it throws everytime, but if you don't log what the exception is, it's hard to figure out where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out what's actually causing it to go to the `.catch()`, you need to find a way to log the actual `err` that the `.catch()` gets.  Usually, that will tell you what caused the promise rejection or at least tell you where to look further.

If you are having trouble logging it on the server, you can also add more info to the response message you send back to the client and get the info there.

FYI, you also have another issue.  When you do `return res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth failed1"});` inside a `.then()`, that's going to send the interpreter onto the next `.then()` handler which is not what you want.

You can simplify your code by doing `throw someError` and sending all the 401 responses to your .catch() where you have a single place to send the 401 response.  This will cause it to skip the other `.then()` handlers which is what you want.